# Register custom_post_type from static function

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am just starting with wordpress plugin development. I want register a new post type when the plugin is activated. But When I activate my plugin nothing happens, no new menu created in the Wordpress Desktop, no errors in apache 'error.log' file.

I guess thin can be caused because the activate() method is static, but I am trying follow the Wordpress.org examples.

I have this:

**main-plugin-file.php**

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_register_activation_hook' );
function plugin_register_activation_hook(){
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-plugin-activator.php';
    CustomPluginActivator::activate();
}
```

**includes/class-plugin-activator.php**

```
class CustomPluginActivator {
 
    public static function activate() {
        add_action('init', array( get_called_class(), 'register_custom_type'));               
    }
        
    function register_custom_type() {
        register_post_type('custom_type',
            array(
                'labels'      => array(
                    'name'          => __('Names',    'textdomain'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Name',     'textdomain'),
                ),
                'description'   => 'Descripción',
                'public'        => true,
                'menu_position' => 2,
                'has_archive'   => false,
                'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'custom-slug' )
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Sorry my english. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the activation hook only will be called when activating the plugin, you will instead need to call `register_post_type()` on some hook which is triggered every time you access the administration pages. You could use the `init` hook for this:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'register_custom_type'));
```

You also need to make the `register_custom_type()` method public for this to work:

```
public function register_custom_type()
{
  // call register_post_type()
}
```

**Documentation**

> Note: Post type registrations should not be hooked before the ‘init’
> action. Also, any taxonomy connections should be registered via the
> $taxonomies argument to ensure consistency when hooks such as
> ‘parse_query’ or ‘pre_get_posts’ are used.

Comment: I understand that I can't add the add_action('init'.. on my "activate" method because this method is executed in the "register" hook (hooks inside hooks are no permited). Anyway, I thougth that types creation are good idea in activate method and unregiser types in the deactivator.

Comment: @user1422434 So did my solution work for you?

Comment: I am in work just now, When I come back home I will test it  an update :) Thanks

Comment: I can test and your answer help me a lot understanding this wordpress feature. Thanks, it's working.